# Wordpress multi site auto activate user after registration

Tags: wordpress, activation, multisite

First of all, I want you all to know that I'm not bothered about spamming on my registration page. I want to aim for something like this.

In my Wordpress Multisite Website, I want users to register their domain/username, but the thing is I don't want to send any email confirmations in their emails, I want the users to be auto activated and redirected to "wp-activate" and show them their username and password after registering.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine a couple of plugins to do what you want:

"Register Plus Redux" to remove the need for email verification, redirect users right after registering, auto login users and not send verification email (or configure the email you want to send to new users).

"Easy Timeout Session" to specify how long the user will be signed in after registering.